# Bottom border overlay content of fieldset

Tags: html, css

I want to accomplish a certain effect in which the bottom border of the fieldset should overlay the content inside it, with a `z-index` lower than the content so it could look like this:

[image]

What I got so far was the simple thing, in which each circle in contained inside the fieldset, but no effect whats so ever.

[image]

The HTML and CSS code follows. Any lead on how to accomplish it is wellcome, I researched but didn't find any documentation of the `fieldset` tag that helped.

```css
fieldset {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 5px dotted rgb(88, 85, 86);
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}

legend {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  max-width: 475px;
  color: rgb(88, 85, 86);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'gotham-book';
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Veja como é fácil participar</legend>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 9%">
      <div class="circles circle-yellow">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="\galeria\repositorio\images\landing\mensalidades-iguais\money.png">
        <p class="yellow-texto">
          Mensalidades que cabem no seu bolso
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="circles circle-yellow">
        <h1 class="yellow-parcelas">12x</h1>
        <p class="yellow-texto">
          parcelas iguais
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="circles circle-red">
        <span class="red-span">R$</span>
        <h1 class="red-parcelas">162</h1>
        <p class="red-texto">
          mensais
        </p>
        <small class="red-small">R$ 1.944,00 ANUAL</small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="circles circle-light-blue">
        <span class="light-blue-span">R$</span>
        <h1 class="light-blue-parcelas">37</h1>
        <p class="light-blue-texto">
          mensais
        </p>
        <p class="light-blue-texto">
          material
        </p>
        <p class="light-blue-texto">
          didático
        </p>
        <small class="light-blue-small">R$ 444,00 ANUAL</small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="circles circle-dark-blue">
        <div class="dark-blue-texto">total</div>
        <span class="dark-blue-span">R$</span>
        <h1 class="dark-blue-parcelas">162</h1>
        <p class="dark-blue-texto">
          mensais
        </p>
        <small class="dark-blue-small">R$ 1.944,00 ANUAL</small>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add [mcve], for example as it is your css has selectors for label and legend -elements but there are none present in the html?

Comment: You can set fieldset height less than circle height and overflow visible. This would work better, if you make the circles inline-block instead float.

Comment: @RauliRajande perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use absolute positioning to take advantage of the z-index, as shown in my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/9dgu2L9t/). I won't bore you with the details you can read more about it here > [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). I'll leave my code below, any further questions feel free to ask.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dotted #f0f;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f0f;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
   <!-- Your Icons here. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> If this answer met your needs don't forget to mark it as correct for other users to find when surfing the web. Thanks.

Regards,
-B

Comment: I actually used the answer given in the comments of my question, I don't want to use a absolute layout for project purposes. But it works just as well, so I market as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. :)